# State Changes but child component didn't re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have new to web development and is trying to learn react and redux.

I am following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC3y8-rFHvwheJHvseC3I0HuYI2f46oAK

As I'm trying to extend what I learned, 
I'm trying to list all the users (clickable), 
once clicked will display (expand/collapse) all the post of the user (clickable again),
once post is clicked, will display (expand/collapse) all the comment on that post

APIs to use:

users: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

posts: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId={user.id}

comments: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId={post.id}

I have added a property `collapse`, on the users array upon fetch for expand/collapse monitoring

My problems are:

1. On my UsersContainer component upon click on the user, the collapse property changes (see on console), however the SampleContainer component didn't hide/show
2. On the tutorial, he said that to change the state we should/must use the action/reducer (forgot the timestamp). 
   Since this is additional property on the array is it ok if I update state on the handleClick function? If no, please give me idea on how to implement this kind of action/reducer.

below is my `UserContainer.js`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { fetchUsers } from "../redux";

function UsersContainer({ userData, fetchUsers }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const handleClick = event => {
    //console.log(userData.users)
    const indx = userData.users.findIndex(obj => obj.id == event.target.value);
    //console.log(indx)
    userData.users[indx].collapse = !userData.users[indx].collapse;
    console.log(userData.users[indx].collapse + " " + indx);
  };

  return userData.loading ? (
    <h2>loading</h2>
  ) : userData.error ? (
    <h2>{userData.error}</h2>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h2>User List</h2>
      <div className="list-group">
        {userData.users.map(user => (
          <div>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
              key={user.id}
              onClick={handleClick}
              value={user.id}
            >
              {user.name}
            </button>
            {/* for update to change SampleContainer component to POST component */}
            {user.collapse && <SampleContainer id={user.id} name={user.name} />}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userData: state.user
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers())
  };
};

const SampleContainer = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* trying to pass the id/name in prep for POST component*/}
      display Posts of - {props.name} ({props.id}){" "}
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UsersContainer);
```

here is the codesandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-testing-mi6ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are directly updating the `userData` props which are immutable i.e is they cannot change and don't update the UI. You will need to update your redux store by dispatching a new action, in this case, it would be `UPDATE_USER_STATUS`.

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-testing-g44jo) with a working example.

Comment: Thank you for this, your answer both resolves my 2 questions, and even provided me a way to implement the redux way to update the state. Thanks much bro.